# DataGrip - How can I copy data from the resultset without the column names?

Tags: datagrip

I'm using DataGrip, having switched from DBeaver a few days ago. One of the things I'd like is to copy the data from the resultset without copying the column names. I copy the data into a spreadsheet which already have the column names and I find it really annoying when I copy the data, and the column names tag along as well. Is there a way I can disable this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the CSV Formats dialog disable the checkbox "First row is header".
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/2016.3/csv-formats-dialog.html

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Do you also happen to know how I can enable grouping for numeric values in the resultset? There are often large numbers and it is a little confusing to read them without the grouping/thousands separator.

Comment: @AshPatel, I don't understand. Can you please be a little clearer? Thanks!

Comment: DataGrip cannot so this, please, follow the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-3988